# operator method and returning "out-of-scope" object?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Box {
public:
  double getVolume(void) {
     return length * breadth * height;
  }
  void setLength( double len ) {
     length = len;
  }
  void setBreadth( double bre ) {
     breadth = bre;
  }
  void setHeight( double hei ) {
     height = hei;
  }

  // Overload + operator to add two Box objects.
  Box operator+(const Box& b) {
     Box box; //local object?
     box.length = this->length + b.length;
     box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
     box.height = this->height + b.height;
     return box;
  }

private:
  double length;      // Length of a box
  double breadth;     // Breadth of a box
  double height;      // Height of a box
};
```

The source of the code: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm. How does the above operator+ work? What I'm confused is that as opposed to Java, in C++ Box box creates an object on the stack, but the method is returning the object whose lifetime is limited to that scope of method (operator).

So I tried another example:

```
template <typename T>
class SmartPointer
{
    T *ptr;
    int numElem; //-1 if an element. >=0 if an array
public:
    SmartPointer(T pNum);
    SmartPointer();
    SmartPointer(T *pArray, int pSize);
    ~SmartPointer();
    SmartPointer(std::initializer_list<T> nums);
    T getValue() const;
    T getValue(int index) const;
    void setValue(T pNum);
    void setValue(T pNum, int index);
    int getNumElem() const;
    SmartPointer<T> operator+ (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
    SmartPointer<T> operator- (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
    SmartPointer<T> operator* (const SmartPointer<T>& ptr);
};

template <class T>
SmartPointer<T> SmartPointer<T>::operator+ (const SmartPointer<T>& p_ptr)
{
        int pSize = this->getNumElem();
        T tempArray[pSize] = {0};
        for(int i = 0; i < this->getNumElem(); i++)
        {
            int result = this->getValue(i) + p_ptr.getValue(i);
            tempArray[i] = result;
        }
        SmartPointer<T> result(tempArray, pSize); (line 60)
        return result; (line 61)
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement smartpointer, and I want to overload + as if it were a componentwise addition (like vector addition).

Then, if I run the following code:

```
SmartPointer<int> sPointer6({10,11,12});
SmartPointer<int> sPointer7({10,11,12});
SmartPointer<int> sPointer8 = sPointer6 + sPointer7;
cout << sPointer8.getValue(0) << endl; //getValue(index)
cout << sPointer8.getValue(1) << endl;
cout << sPointer8.getValue(2) << endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
1310912
1338712
24
```

But if I replace line 60 and line 61 by

```
return SmartPointer<T>(tempArray, pSize);
```

Then I get the following output:

```
20
22
24
```

Why am I getting different outputs? And why does the first example work but not the smartpointer example?

Comment: How is the first code pastie relevant to the question?

Comment: Because in both cases I created local variables and return them but the output of the second example seems like I am trying to access invalid address, whereas the first example works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I'm confused is that as opposed to Java, in C++ Box box creates an object on the stack, but the method is returning the object whose lifetime is limited to that scope of method (operator).

```
  Box operator+(const Box& b) {
     Box box; //local object?
     // ...
     return box;
  }
```

Correct but this isn't a problem because the object is **copied**.
The `Box` object define a implicit default "copy constructor" (with signature `Box (Box const & b)`) and an implicit `operator=()` (with signature `Box & (Box const & b)`. Starting from C++11, also a "move constructor" (with signature `Box (Box && b)`) and a `Box & operator=(Box const & b)`

So, when you write

```
Box a, b, c;

// ...

Box d { a + b };
c = a + b;
```

the `operator+()` create a temporary `Box` (`result`) that is copied (or moved) in `d`, through copy or move constructor, or in `c`, through `operator=()`, before it's destruction.

For `Box`, default copy/move constructors and `operator=()`'s are OK because there isn't involved memory allocation or other complex operations (they simply copy  `length`, `breadth`, `height`).

The problems arises with your `SmartPointer` that (if I understand correctly) dynamically allocated memory (for `ptr`).

A default constructor (etc.) ins't OK anymore because it **copy** the value of `ptr` that is (destructing the temporary object) immediately deallocated (if you have added `delete[]` in `~SmartPointer()`.

The result is that when you write

```
SmartPointer<int> sPointer8 = sPointer6 + sPointer7;
```

the `ptr` in `sPointer8` points to a memory area that is free. And that the program can use for other purposes (other variables).

```
So, when you get

1310912
1338712
24
```

it's because (I suppose) the memory that was reserved for `result[0]` and `result[1]` in the temporary `sPointer6 + sPointer7` is free and reused for one or more other variables.

The fact that you get different results from

```
    SmartPointer<T> result(tempArray, pSize);
    return result;
```

and from

```
    return SmartPointer<T>(tempArray, pSize);
```

it's a pure fatality, because in both cases you're accessing free memory that is, in both case, UB (Undefined Bahaviour).

And UB mean: anything can happen.

Solution: write copy/move constructors, and both `operator=()` to manage the duplication and copy of memory allocated in `ptr`.

Or, better, avoid the direct management of memory and use containers/smart pointers available in standard libraries.

Another point:

```
    int pSize = this->getNumElem();
    T tempArray[pSize] = {0};
```

isn't (standard C++): you can't initialize a C-style array with a run-time value.

Answer (score 1):

Your template class `SmartPointer` does not define `operator=` and copying constructor, thus a default `operator=` or copying constructor is defined. The returned copy `sPointer8`references freed array `ptr`. It is UB, it comes due to violated The Rule of Free.

You would not meet such error if you would use `std::vector<T>` instead of C-array `ptr` and its size `numElem`.

Comment: @Ted The class `Box` does not deal with the heap memory, a dynamically allocated array.